# Stuck on perl regex expression for string with ending white space

Tags: regex, perl

Following is a line from an ftp log:

> 2013-03-05 18:37:31 543.21.12.22 []sent
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/court-9746hd/Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg
>   226 court-9746hd@mydomain.com 256

I am using a program called Simple Event Correlate which pulls values from inside the parenthesis of a regex expression and sets those values to a variable.

So, here is an entry in a SEC config file which is supposed to operate on the previous log file line:

```
    pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/(.*)\/(.*)
```

This succeeds in pulling out the logged in user, `court-9746hd`, and setting it to a variable, but fails to properly extract the file name downloaded, or, `Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg`

Instead, it pulls out the file downloaded as: `Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg 226 court-9746hd@mydomain.com 256`

So you see, I'm having difficulty getting the second extraction to stop at the first white space after the file name.  I've tried:

```
    pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/(.*)\/(.*)\s
```

but I only get the same result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to match non-whitespace, replace `.*` with `\S*` or if space is the only character you want to exclude then use `[^ ]*` instead.

Also, `man perlre` is a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the .* construct, use something narrower in scope, as a general rule. In this case what you want is something which is not a white space, so say that explicitly:

```
pattern=sent \/home\/mydomain\/public_html\/([^\s]+)\/([^\s]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to first capture the full path from the line, and then use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) to get the user and file info:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my $line = '2013-03-05 18:37:31 543.21.12.22 []sent /home/mydomain/public_html/court-9746hd/Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg 226 court-9746hd@mydomain.com 256';
my ( $path ) = $line =~ m!\s+(/home\S+)\s+!;
my ( $user, $file ) = ( File::Spec->splitdir($path) )[ -2, -1 ];

print "User: $user\nFile: $file";
```

Output:

```
User: court-9746hd
File: Chairman-confidential-video.mpeg
```

However, if you want to only use a regex, the following will work:

```
m!/home/.+/.+/([^/]+)/(\S+)!
```